# Splitting a string in sql for all characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2016

I am trying to split a string in SQL on the space delimiter. The number of spaces changes, so there can be values for 4 or 5 columns. I am trying using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`, but can't get past the first delimiter.

**Example:**

input would be `'444 Addison Avenue SA 5222'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split into columns, you could use a little XML in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('444 Addison Avenue SA 5222')
,('1 Washington Square')


Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace([SomeCol],' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks John, but I get a XML parsing error.
XML parsing: line 1, character 13, illegal name character

Comment: @Sth3 I suspect you have some non-XML safe text.  One moment

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Can you explain what this `§§Split§§` is please?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze  Just a little trick picked up from Snugo (XML Ninja).  The idea is to create a delimiter of a truly UNIQUE string... something you would not see in the real world.  hth.

Comment: Thanks,  @JohnCappelletti, I'll play around that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result only with *XML-based* splitting:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE ([Address] varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('444 Addison Avenue SA 5222'),('1 Washington Square')

SELECT T.[Address]
    ,AddressElements.value(N'/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Element_1 
    ,AddressElements.value(N'/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Element_2 
    ,AddressElements.value(N'/x[3]','varchar(max)') AS Element_3 
    ,AddressElements.value(N'/x[4]','varchar(max)') AS Element_4 
    ,AddressElements.value(N'/x[5]','varchar(max)') AS Element_5 
FROM ( 
    SELECT [Address]
        ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([Address],' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS AddressElements 
    FROM @tmp 
) T
```

Results:

[image]